# How to combine different data from microservices to one central place?

Tags: architecture, microservices

After some research about microservice, I find out that it may only about project partition. And I have a question towards microservice is that if I want to merge all data from microservices into one space? e.g. Building a admin panel to manage all the data

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve.  can you please explain?

Comment: i think what you are looking for is a dashboard , check this out once  - https://dzone.com/articles/mircoservices-dashboard

Comment: Sure, I am building a dashboard that via multiple microservices, and it needs data from a bunch of api from different services. That complicates the implementation of dashboard. So I would like to seek a way to make it simple enough.